# Determining if a file exists and finding a string in a line of a file (.txt) and returning true or false if found Java HW

Tags: java, string, file

This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. I've been stumped with this question for the longest time now and I do know what's wrong with my code. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Q1: Write a `public static` method named q1 that takes no parameters and has return type `boolean`. This method will attempt to open a file named **school.txt** and returns `true` if the file exists and contains the String "**test**" as a sub-String on any line, and `false` if "**test**" is not found. This method will also return `false` if "**school.txt**" does not exist.

```
public static boolean q1() {


    try{
        String fileName = "";

        if(fileName == "school.txt");{
            for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("school.txt"))){
                String[] data = line.split(",");{

                    for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
                        if(data[i].contains("test"));{
                            return true;
            }
        }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hint: your if statement will never evaluate to "true"

Comment: What behaviour or errors are you seeing?

Comment: Second hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @Kevin But the semicolon next to it means the if actually doesn't even control anything i.e. basically a no-op.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create and write files , return boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344198/create-and-write-files-return-boolean)

Comment: Read about debugging code

Comment: @Vasan Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides having the semicolon by the end of your `if` (which means `if` is not gonna be used), you have used `contains()`. If your file is just words being separated by colons, you should use `data[i].equals("test")`. So if your file is like the below file, `equals()` will do the charm.

> hello, world, test, bye,

But if your file is something like this:

> hello world, test is in progress, viva la vida, bye,

you need to examine each word separately, so you need to write a method to check each `data[i]` for the word **test**.

In any of the cases above, use `trim()` method so your String will not contain any white spaces so it could be compared with **test**.

Answer (score 0):

why used ; after if statement it will terminate the condition and when you will set the file name as you initialize with `String filename=""`; so better to pass the name of file in `q1()` method
comparing the string with == is not recommended use `equals` method instead

```
public static boolean q1(String fileName) {


        try{
            //String fileName = "";

            if(fileName.equals("school.txt")){/*no need to put ; otherwise it will terminate here*/
                for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("school.txt"))){
                    String[] data = line.split(",");

                    for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
                        if(data[i].contains("test")){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean q1()
    {
        try
        {
            String fileName = ""; //you create this, but never set it to anything else, and only use it once, in an operation that does nothing.  might as well not be here

            if (fileName == "school.txt") ; //you have an if statement that will never evaluate to "true" followed by a ; this line essentially does nothing and might as well not be here
            {//unnecessary bracket
                for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("school.txt")))// You are reading in all the lines, don't see a logic problem here
                {
                    String[] data = line.split(",");//why are you splitting the lines?  The problem statment says nothing about that.
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)// iterating through each line
                        {
                            if (data[i].contains("test")) ;// another semicolon directly after the if, line might as well not be here
                            {// unnecessary bracket
                                return true;
                            }//closing of unnecessary bracket
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//closing of unnecessary bracket
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So let's clean this up, remove all the stuff that does nothing, and see if you can find the bug

```
public static boolean q1()
{
    try
    {
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("school.txt"))) // You are reading in all the lines, don't see a logic problem here
        {
            String[] data = line.split(","); //why are you splitting the lines?  The problem statment says nothing about that.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) // iterating every line
                {
                    return true; //returning true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```